# After Updating Angular 14 to 15 getting SassError: Undefined Variable error

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular15, mdc-components, angular-material-15

- I've updated angular 14 to 15 and material to 15.
- ng generate @angular/material:mdc-migration
- delete node_modules and package-lock files and npm cache clean --force then reinstall it.
- ng serve I'm getting SassError: Undefined variable.
- npm ls @material/elevation

[image]

[image: Material error]

Package.json file.

```
 "dependencies": {
"@agm/core": "^3.0.0-beta.0",
"@angular/animations": "^15.2.9",
"@angular/cdk": "^15.2.9",
"@angular/common": "^15.2.9",
"@angular/compiler": "^15.2.9",
"@angular/core": "^15.2.9",
"@angular/forms": "^15.2.9",
"@angular/localize": "^15.2.9",
"@angular/material": "^15.2.9",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^15.2.9",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.2.9",
"@angular/router": "^15.2.9",
"@angular/service-worker": "^15.2.9",
"@azure/msal-angular": "^2.3.3",
"@azure/msal-browser": "^2.27.0",
"@material/tabs": "^2.3.0",
"@microsoft/signalr": "^6.0.8",
"@ngx-translate/core": "^14.0.0",
"@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^7.0.0",
"@ag-grid-community/angular": "^28.2.0",
"@ag-grid-community/client-side-row-model": "^28.2.0",
"@ag-grid-community/styles": "^28.2.0",
"@ag-grid-enterprise/excel-export": "^28.2.0",
"@ag-grid-enterprise/master-detail": "^28.2.0",
"@ag-grid-enterprise/set-filter": "^28.2.0",
"@ag-grid-enterprise/row-grouping": "^28.2.0",
"@ag-grid-enterprise/menu": "^28.2.0",
"@ag-grid-enterprise/clipboard": "^28.2.0",
"@ag-grid-enterprise/column-tool-panel": "^28.2.0",
"bootstrap": "^5.2.0",
"file-saver": "^2.0.5",
"jszip": "^3.10.1",
"lodash": "^4.17.21",
"moment": "^2.29.4",
"ngx-mask": "^13.1.15",
"ngx-pendo": "^1.10.0",
"ngx-quill": "^16.2.1",
"quill": "^1.3.7",
"quill-emoji": "^0.2.0",
"quill-mention": "^3.1.0",
"rxjs": "^7.5.6",
"tslib": "^2.4.0",
"zone.js": "^0.11.8",
"powerbi-client-angular": "^3.0.5"
```

any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: are the variables supposed to be coming from node_modules? e.g. if they are defined in bootstrap then search the "node_modules/bootstrap" folder for the definition of the undefined variables and import them from there

Comment: can you run `npm ls @material/elevation` ?

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler I run the command and updated the SS in POST. Please check.

Comment: @danday74. I'm using only row and column classes from bootstrap. and I import bootstrap in Angular. Json file.
ex. "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",

Comment: bootstrap was just an example - is there another node_package you are using variables from? e.g. material

Comment: @danday74 I'm using this only.
{ provide: MAT_TABS_CONFIG, useValue: { animationDuration: '0ms' } },

Comment: Which Node.js version are you using? Odds are the version was compatible with Angular 14.x but is no longer compatible with 15.x. You can check this using `node -v`. For the compatibility table see [here}(https://angular.io/guide/versions).

Comment: I found the solution. Thank you for the help all of you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried one more time to **delete node_modules and package-lock files and npm cache clean --force then reinstall it**. and this time it worked. All the sass error gone.